# How to find textbox in Watir

Tags: ruby, dom, screen-scraping, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to access a site with watir-webdriver, but I can't seem to find a textbox in watir that I can see in Firefox+Firebug.

My code is

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'irb/completion'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
browser.goto('http://emersonecologics.com/')
browser.text_field(:name, "txtEmail").set("myemail@gmail.com")
```

I get the error:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:type=>"(any text type)", :name=>"txtEmail", :tag_name=>"input or textarea"}
```

However, I know there is a textbox named txtEmail because Firebug shows me

```
<input id="txtEmail" class="textbox" type="text" tabindex="1" name="txtEmail">
```

Of course, it is this textbox is deep inside the tree. So, thinking that I should navigate to it in the DOM, I tried to access the div called 'all'.

If I do

```
>>browser.divs[1].id
=> "all"
>> browser.divs[1].tag_name
=> "div"
```

But when I try to get a handle to it as following, it seems I cant locate it.

```
>>browser.div(:id, "all")
=> #<Watir::Div:0x101a8fd70 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"div", :id=>"all"}>
```

Can anyone help me how to select objects in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's in a frame to me also

to avoid confusion over indexes (especially given variences in how various flavors of Watir are either 0 based or 1 based) I'd suggest identifying it by name.  See if this will flash it.

```
browser.frame(:id, "ctrlLoginSSL_ifLogin").text_field(:id, "txtEmail").flash
```

See the [Watir Wiki page on frames](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames) for more info on dealing with stuff inside a frame

P.S.

Note (related to the site, and it's use of frames):  You might also mention to the site developers that some browsers such as chrome are noting an inconsistency of the protocol for the frame (https) not matching the outer container (http)  Chrome's developer tools is issuing the following complaint

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access
>   frame with URL
>   https://www.emersonecologics.com/User/LoginFrame.aspx?redir=/default.aspx
>   from frame with URL
>   http://emersonecologics.com/. Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the element you are trying to access is inside a frame. I was able to set the email with:

browser.frame(:index, 1).text_field(:name, "txtEmail").set("myemail@gmail.com")

For more info: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames

Comment: That's funny because this is what I get:
Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException: unable to locate frame/iframe using {:index=>1}.
Are you using Firefox and watir-webdriver?

Comment: @Zeljko, that works, thanks! Though it says <Watir::TextField:0x7fcf95de6298 located=false selector={:type=>"(any text type)", :tag_name=>"input or textarea", :name=>"txtEmail"}. Shouldn't it say located=true?

Comment: As I understand it, it always says `located=false` until you actually access the element.

Comment: @Željko, ahh, that makes it so much less confusing.